# UpdateSourceTrigger not working with converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I am changing the progress bar based on how many items are in the list. Below code works fine.

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="2" Value="{Binding ProgressList.Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

But what I really need is not `ProgressList.Count` but `ProgressList.Where(x => x.Done).Count()` so I changed my xaml to:

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="2" Value="{Binding ProgressList, Converter={StaticResource DoneProgressConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

and made a converter:

```
public class DoneProgressConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((ObservableCollection<SetupProgress>)value).Where(x => x.Done).Count();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But it seems that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` doesn't trigger anymore because it enters my converter only once (immediately after running the application).

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger` works from `Target(View)` To `Source(VM`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `Property` and update it from your `ViewModel` and `bind` it to your `progress bar`. in that way you will `notify View` by changing the property binded.

```
 private int _Progress;
    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _Progress; }
        set
        {
            _Progress= value;                
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now Bind it to progress bar and update the property by,

```
 Progress = ProgressList.Where(x => x.Done).Count();
```

or add to the Setter of your List to Modify when you add new items.

```
 private ObservableCollection<yourClass>_ProgressList;
    public ObservableCollection<yourClass> ProgressList
    {
        get { return _ProgressList; }
        set
        {
            _ProgressList= value;                
            Progress = ProgressList.Where(x => x.Done).Count();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Note : `UpdateSourceTrigger` works from `Target(View)` To `Source(VM)`

Comment: so you suggest every time that I push an item in my ProgressList it should be followed by `Progress = ProgressList.Where(x => x.Done).Count();`?

Comment: Yes that is how you can notify `View` from `VM`. `NotifyPropertyChanged();` in the setter will be notifying your `View`

Comment: I would like something "automated", isn't there any other way?

Comment: Added an edit please check. i am not sure if we have any other way to this.